# Multiplying by diagnonal matrix (provided as vector) in Eigen

Tags: eigen

Given a matrix `A` and a vector `d` that represents the diagonal of a diagonal matrix D, what would be the best (i.e. simplest without compromising performance) Eigen expression for D*`A` in terms of only `d` and `A`?

Constructing `D` (as a dense matrix) and doing `D*A` seems inefficient as it would involve unnecessary multiplications by zero. The rows of `A` simply need to be scaled by the corresponding elements of `d`.

Should I convert to array and scale the rows or does Eigen provide for diagonal matrices to be constructed and multiplied in a way that avoids unnecessary overhead?

Comment: There is a `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix` type. I guess it should correspond to your need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `Eigen::DiagonalMatrix`, as [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835331/multiplying-by-diagnonal-matrix-provided-as-vector-in-eigen#comment105808344_59835331) suggested. Alternatively, if you're already given an `Eigen::Vector` (or `Map`), you can use [`d.asDiagonal()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a14235b62c90f93fe910070b4743782d0) as follows:

```
Eigen::VectorXf d;
Eigen::MatrixXf a, b;
b = d.asDiagonal() * a;
```